# stringWithContentsOfURL and HTTP 500 error codes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to pull some data from a server (I don't own the server) however it returns some needed data with a http 500 error code, however NSString stringWithContentsOfURL returns nil if the server returns http code 500.

I'd like to retrieve the data even if the server returns 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) (as part of the [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)) will give you the lower-level control over the request and the interpretation of the response; you will have to implement a few call-back methods to handle fine grained control of the request (and you can opt to invoke it synchronously to mimic `stringWithContentsOfURL:`, but it will give you what you want.

`[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:]` is a great convenience, but in your case you want to circumvent the way cocoa interprets HTTP response codes, so that requires a smidge more work.

Answer (score 1):

You can carefully use this code (never from GUI thread):

```
NSURLRequest * request = ...

NSError * error = nil;
NSURLResponse * response = nil;

NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                      returningResponse:&response 
                                                  error:&error];

NSInteger httpCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
```